# ARKit Relocalization not working after .resetTracking

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

In my ARKit app I have the "sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization" delegate method returning true so that the session can resume after an interruption.

```
func sessionShouldAttemptRelocalization(_ session: ARSession) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This works perfectly, and after any interruption, if the user goes back to the original place + holds the devices roughly under the same orientation, all the objects will get automatically adjusted.

However, the issue I'm having is that, if the user resets the configuration once, further relocalizations will fail.

For example:

1. User places the AR objects.
2. User interrupts the session. (Brings down the Notification Center, and waits a couple of seconds)
3. User resumes the session and goes back to the original position. **(Here everything goes well and things are displayed the same way they were before the interruption. This can be repeated multiple times and it will work every time)**
4. User interrupts the session.
5. User resumes the session and before the relocalization succeeds the user presses the "Reset AR Button"
6. User places other AR objects.
7. User interrupts the session.
8. User resumes the session. **(Here the relocalization will never succeed. This can be repeated multiple times, by pressing the "Reset AR Button", placing new objects, interrupting, resuming and trying to relocalize them. It will never work)**

The method I'm using to reset the tracking is the following:

```
func resetTracking() {
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking])

    // ... code to remove all nodes...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new session instead of reset tracking. I don't know whether or not this is correct answer or good idea. But this trick worked for me

```
func resetTracking() {
    self.sceneView.session = ARSession()
    self.session = self.sceneView.session
    self.session.delegate = self
    self.session.run(self.configuration)
}
```